# putExtra and getStringExtra not working

Tags: android

I have checked the code a dozen times. There doesn't seem to be anything but annoyingly, it's not working.

I'm simply using putExtra to pass data from one activity to another. The second activity always gets **null** from the getStringExtra method.

Here is the code:

```
dataViewHolder.setClickListener(new DataViewHolder.ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v, int pos, boolean isLongClick) {
            con.startActivity(new Intent(con, Products.class).putExtra("category", "33"));
        }
});
```

The second activity. Here, getStringExtra always returns **null**, as in the string null.

```
Intent i = new Intent();

new GetJson().execute(url + i.getStringExtra("category"));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the second Activity you should use the intent that launched the Activity :

```
Intent i = getIntent();
```

and not create a new one :

```
Intent i = new Intent();
```

Comment: This worked. I am curious though. What I posted above is working fine for me in another app. Why not here?

Comment: That must not work, creating a `new Intent` will always create a new instance, so that Intent is always empty... I am curious about this `another app`

Comment: I just checked it. It's not working. Thankfully it was just a test app I made to check a particular thing so the error didn't reveal itself. Such a basic error. Thanks. I'll mark your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can get it from getStringExtra method via getIntent method.

```
new GetJson().execute(url + getIntent().getStringExtra("category"));
```

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a new Intent in SecondActivity and trying to get data from it. That's why it's always returning **null**,

As @Gorcyn stated,

Replace `Intent i = new Intent();`
with `Intent i = getIntent();`

This will get the intent which started the *Activity*.